# Why does console.log not trigger proxy getter trap?

Tags: javascript

I have following code:

```
let p = new Proxy([1, 2, 3], {   
  get: function() {   
    console.log('get')   
  }   
})
console.log(p)
```

I think `Proxy` should proxy **everything** about `[1,2,3]`.

When I `log` value, it should read value from `[1,2,3]`, so the getter should be triggered.

But when I set a breakpoint in the getter, the breakpoint is not hit?

Why don't `console.log` and `console.table` trigger the getter function?

Comment: @demo demo has changed my codes, if you click `run code snippet`, it will show `get` log message, **but** if you run above codes in dev tools, it don't print `get`

Comment: Note that Browsers' consoles log the Proxy object itself in this case, not the proxified one.

Comment: Because the console can use the debugger API to inspect the value directly, e.g. accessing the proxy target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the console's behaviour is not specified in this case, it depends on your engine on wether it hits the trap or not. [NodeJS does for example](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/12453).

IMO chromes way to not trigger the trap is better. I want the console to be an independent observer of the code, if it changes the way the code behaves, debugging will get more painful ("was that trap triggered by some code or by the console?").

Comment: Yes, you are right, chrome not trigger but nodejs does. but nodejs use V8, which same as chrome, why has different result. Did nodejs developer change codes?

Comment: @toffee yes, they use different console implementations (dunno why)

Comment: @toffee V8 is just the interpreter and does not include library code like `console`. Remember, Node does not even have a `window` object like browsers.

Comment: @slebetman V8 does however implement the debugger API (not sure why they haven't taken over the command line, the NodeJS console is not that useful at all ...)

Comment: @slebetman got it! I think I should go wikipedia to find out what actually interpreter is...

Answer (score 4):

That's because you are logging the Proxy object itself.
The browser console has access to its internal state, which is an Object with two or three internal properties: `[[target]]`, `[[handler]]` and `[[IsRevoked]]`.

You may note that Chrome does by default expands the `[[target]]` in its collapsed message:

[image: console output of Chrome]

while Firefox choose to expose only the Proxy object by default <sub>(and doesn't expose an [[isRevoked]] internal, they set `<target>` and `<handler>` to null to signal revoked Proxies).</sub>
[image]

So as to **how** they are able to not trigger the trap, well they take the internal [[target]] shortcut and access directly to the original Object.