# Why does logging a proxy to the console show the target object, bypassing the traps?

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

Hey I am currently taking a closer look at JavaScript Proxies at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

The second example defines a handler to intercept the `get` operation:

```
const target = {
  message1: "hello",
  message2: "everyone"
};

const handler2 = {
  get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
    return "world";
  }
};

const proxy2 = new Proxy(target, handler2);
```

After that it logs both `target` properties to the console:

```
console.log(proxy2.message1); // world
console.log(proxy2.message2); // world
```

If you however log the object itself to the console it logs the object and ignores the handler:

```
console.log(proxy2); // { message1: 'hello', message2: 'everyone' }
```

Why is that the case?

Comment: I get `Proxy {message1: 'hello', message2: 'everyone'}` on v8, `Proxy { <target>: {…}, <handler>: {…} }` on FF, but not the log you show.

Comment: PS: also see [why-does-console-log-not-trigger-proxy-getter-trap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55630414/why-does-console-log-not-trigger-proxy-getter-trap), note that the console output is from what i know not programmatically accessible. It may potentially display internal data, for an in some sense "elevated user" (devtool user), depending on the engine. Note, that even overwriting member access, one could still read the original data of the proxy from code (but not get a reference to the target object itself), as you didn't trap `ownKeys` or `getOwnPropertyDescriptor`.

Comment: "*If you however log the object itself to the console it logs the object and ignores the handler*" - I cannot reproduce. What console are you using?